# Image properties given by similitude moments

Tags: computer-vision

What image properties are given by similitude moments? These are image moments of the form shown below:

$$\eta_{pq}=\frac{\sum_x\sum_y(x-\mu_x)^p(y-\mu_y)^qI(x,y)}{(\sum_x\sum_yI(x,y))^{\frac{p+q}{2}+1}}$$

Specifically, I'm looking for the properties given by this set of similitude moments:

[$\eta_{02}$, $\eta_{03}$, $\eta_{11}$, $\eta_{12}$, $\eta_{20}$, $\eta_{21}$, $\eta_{30}$]

I wasn't able to find many relevant results on Google. Those that mentioned similitude image moments just said how to calculate it, not what they're used for.

Comment: Is it by any chance from the descriptors (scale and translation invariant) for silhouette recognition arbitrarily chosen compact set? Are you interested in general description why these particular moments or want insight about every given one? By properties you mean the textual description what it exactly measures?

Comment: I'm looking for a general description of what these moments measure